# Django query, finding the maximum object

Tags: django, django-models

I'm hitting my head on something that should be simple.

I have a query like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...).aggregate(max_value=Max('value'))
```

and this does, indeed, return a (dictionary) with key 'max_value' and value that maximum value.

But what I want is the *object* that has that maximum value.  Or, at least, some subset of the fields of that object, but the max value is just the selector

Answer (score 2):

You can work with the [**`.latest(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) to obtain the object with the maximum of certain field(s). This will internally order the queryset and then obtain the last object, so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(…).latest('value')
```